# Why does yahoo_fin cause 'adjclose' error when downloading Apple stock?

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance

When I try to download the current price from apple with the help from yahoo_fin (see below) the I receive the error message KeyError: 'adjclose'.
Anyone knows why and how to fix it?

Thank you

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
ab=si.get_live_price('APPL')
print(ab)  ´´´

Complete Erro massage:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-71-71025ce2a3a4> in <module>
      1 #self._history["Current Price"]=self._history["Ticker"].apply(lambda x: si.get_live_price(x))
----> 2 ab=si.get_live_price('APPL')
      3 ab

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Financial-Project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in get_live_price(ticker)
    397     '''    
    398 
--> 399     df = get_data(ticker, end_date = pd.Timestamp.today() + pd.DateOffset(10))
    400 
    401 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Financial-Project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in get_data(ticker, start_date, end_date, index_as_date, interval)
     86 
     87     # add in adjclose
---> 88     frame["adjclose"] = data["chart"]["result"][0]["indicators"]["adjclose"][0]["adjclose"]
     89 
     90     # get the date info

KeyError: 'adjclose'

´´´
```

Comment: I think Yahoo use 'AdjClose__' as the key for adjusted close. What are the column headers you get if you print ab?

Comment: Well i cannot print ab because gives me the error immediately. So the function si.get_live_price('APPL'), seems not to work with apple. But it works for other tickers such as JP Morgan ("JPM") for example. 
I am wondering if it has something to do with dividend payments, that for those companies adjusted prices need to be retrieved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Apple ticker is **"AAPL"** (not "APPL"). Your code runs correctly with that update.

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
ab=si.get_live_price('AAPL')
print(ab) 
134.99000549316406
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual says it is not case sensitive, but you can get it by using lower case.

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info
ab=stock_info.get_live_price('aapl')
print(ab)

129.41000366210938
```